# Very simple JavaScript the page is not recognizing my js file

Tags: javascript

My page is not "recognizing" the js file

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./themes/self.js"></script>
</head>
```

there is self.js file inside the themes directory

and inside self.js the only statement is

```
alert("Alert Window");
```

Comment: and where is the themes directory relative to your page file directory?

Comment: there is the html file and then in the same level there is a directory named themes

Comment: I believe it could be just the relative path issue :-). Also try copying the code to the script tag.

Comment: Try an absolute path.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, true, myself included :) Any ideas?

Comment: What does "not recognizing" mean? Is it throwing an error in the dev tools console?

Comment: @Sergio No idea. That's why I'm not answering yet :p

Comment: Did you get this working? can you post more info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the path of the js file relative to your html file. Is your html file in the parent folder of theme? You can also use absolute path from the root

Comment: Read the comments. "there is the html file and then in the same level there is a directory named themes". And in the question: "there is self.js file inside the themes directory".

Comment: Why down vote? When I wrote the response it was not updated yet. Also regardless it does not make my answer wrong or false

Comment: The comment I quoted was posted a good three minutes before your answer.

Comment: It does not matter how long if my browser does not trigger that there is an update. plus my response was not wrong. He DOES need to check his path and he CAN use absolute path. Stop abusing your vote. Whats next down vote for typo?

Comment: Downvote for not uppercasing the acronym "HTML"... or something equally sarcastic.

Comment: -shrugs- My logic goes like this: 3 people agreed with my comment. Nobody agreed with your answer. That puts me three points up over you...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That doesn't mean you need to aggravate the situation with snarky comments. azzerd Your answer is arguably a comment. Plus, you have the ability to edit your answer, which is there in part for these kinds of situations where you have seen new information that potentially invalidates or alters your answer.

Comment: Thanks ajp15243 for being unbias. but I still see nothing wrong with the response. The Q 'Is your html file in the parent folder of theme' is not a Q that I required answer for in order to solve the issue. it was there to get the OP to check his code.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Just for that, I'm voting the other way!